# Copy twig array to javascript Object

Tags: php, twig

I have array in twig sent by php script.

You can access the each value as in html file like this below.

```
{% for a in myArray %}
{{a.date}}{{a.high}}
{% endfor %}
```

However Now I want to put the data in each object.
How can I do this??

```
<script>
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        chartData[i] = ({
            date: newDate,//to use value from twig array!!
            high: high,
            low: low,
        });
</srcipt>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Twig's json_encode filter ( It's using PHP's json_encode function )

```
<script>
    var chartData = {{ myArray|json_encode() }}
</script>
```